# Avoiding conflicting complex types

Tags: entity-framework

Using entity framework with multiple `.edmx` files, I've run into the problem where if I have for example one `.edmx` file with a function import called `Foo` it will create a complex type `Foo_Result`. But if I have another `.edmx` with a function `Foo` it will also create a `Foo_Result` and EF doesn't seem to complain about the ambiguity until you try and use a `Foo_Result` and find you've got the wrong one.

This in particular popped up when I moved a function from one database to another and after making some changes an "update model from database" in the database that `Foo` used to live in causes `Foo_Result` to be recreated (even though `Foo` itself was not) and overwrote the previous one.

Comment: You can (and should) create a new complex type to map the function result to. See the edit dialog of the function import.

Comment: @GertArnold: The problem is, if you go to your `edmx` file, right-click on the designer and select "update model from database", then in the update wizard select a stored procedure, EF goes ahead and does this for you automatically. It doesn't give you the opportunity to map to a new complex type.

Comment: Sure, but you can do it afterwards.